# Famo.us drag & drop surfaces?

Tags: drag-and-drop, famo.us

I've gone through the handy [Famo.us University](https://famo.us/university) tutorials and am prototyping a drag & drop interface.  It's the typical UI where the user can drag an icon and drop it onto a target to do something. I've gotten the drag part down, but detecting the drop is getting very hairy. Is there built-in collision detection in Famo.us?

Edit: I've looked at the [Collision API](https://famo.us/docs/physics/Collision) but it's not clear whether this would work across views.

Here's how I've organized the project:

```
AppView (overall container)
 |
 |__ MenuView (sidebar) --> VizView (icons in MenuView)
 |
 |__ PageView (workspace where the drop targets live)
```

This may not be the best way to go about this. I'm not sure. Hooking up input events across the views seems to be painful.

VizView source:

```
/*** VizView.js ***/

define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var View          = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface       = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Transform     = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var ImageSurface  = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');

    var Transitionable = require("famous/transitions/Transitionable");
    var SnapTransition = require("famous/transitions/SnapTransition");
    Transitionable.registerMethod("spring", SnapTransition);

    var GenericSync     = require('famous/inputs/GenericSync');
    var MouseSync       = require('famous/inputs/MouseSync');
    var TouchSync       = require('famous/inputs/TouchSync');
    GenericSync.register({'mouse': MouseSync, 'touch': TouchSync});

    function VizView() {
        View.apply(this, arguments);

        _createIcon.call(this);
    }

    VizView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    VizView.prototype.constructor = VizView;

    VizView.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        angle: -0.2,
        iconSize: 98,
        iconUrl: '',
        title: 'Empty',
        fontSize: 26
    };

    function _createIcon() {
        this.zIndex = 0;
        var me = this;

        var iconSurface = new ImageSurface({
            size: [this.options.iconSize, this.options.iconSize],
            content : this.options.iconUrl,
            properties: {
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        });

        var initModifier = new Modifier({
            // places the icon in the proper location
            transform: Transform.translate(24, 2, 0)
        });

        this.position = new Transitionable([0, 0]);
        var positionModifier = new Modifier({
            transform : function(){
                var currentPosition = me.position.get();
                return Transform.translate(currentPosition[0], currentPosition[1], me.zIndex);
            },
        });

        var sync = new GenericSync(
            ['mouse', 'touch']
        );
        sync.on('start', function(data){
            me.zIndex = 1;
        });
        sync.on('update', function(data){
            me.updateIcon(data);
        });
        sync.on('end', function(data){
            var velocity = data.velocity;
            me.position.set([0, 0], {
                method : 'spring',
                period : 150,
                velocity : velocity
            });
            me.zIndex = 0;
        });

        iconSurface.pipe(sync);
        this.add(positionModifier).add(initModifier).add(iconSurface);

        this.updateIcon = function (data) {
            if (this.zIndex == 0) return;
            var currentPosition = this.position.get();
            this.position.set([
                currentPosition[0] + data.delta[0],
                currentPosition[1] + data.delta[1]
            ]);
        }
    }

    module.exports = VizView;
});
```

A VizView is instantiated in MenuView as such:

```
        var vizView = new VizView({
            iconUrl: "path/to/iconUrl",
            title: "Viz Title"
        });

        var vizModifier = new StateModifier({
            transform: Transform.translate(0, yOffset, 0)
        });

        this.add(vizModifier).add(vizView);
```

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out an ideal solution for what you're trying to achieve @pmont. I can't guarantee I'll come up with something, but if I do I'll definitely post it here. Many minds make light work aye?

Comment: @KraigWalker I appreciate your contributions. Teamwork FTW! 
We can [listen for HTML5 DOM events on Famous surfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614367/droppable-in-famous-js). I'm having trouble getting Famo.us Draggable surfaces to fire off those events. The event listeners appear to be swallowing them.

Comment: For the time being, I'm setting aside the Famous event handlers and using HTML5 drag/drop events. They can be used on surfaces as described in the link above. Here's a [primer on HTML drag/drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/).  This unfortunately means that I won't be able to leverage Famous's physics engine for transition effects.

Comment: Not sure of I'm right on this, but I was under the belief that the drag and drop API was for *files* - ie allow a user to drag a photo file from their desktop and upload it to Facebook.

Comment: HTML5 drag/drop was created with that in mind (filesList member points to that). However it can be used with any element, dragging from or dropping onto.

Answer (score 1):

A `draggable` `Surface` in `Famo.us` is not really a `DOM draggable` element although it can be setup to work in a browser using the mouse.  I have not been able to get `GenericSync` and `touch` to work with this solution yet.

Reading the pitfalls on the Famo.us site, there are hints to `drag and drop` with surface draggables being an issue.

> [How do I find the absolute position of a Surface on the screen?](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/fcbfbaf3161c5090b35dee73819b29fe5f2cb41f/guides/pitfalls.md#how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-a-surface-on-the-screen)
>
> By design this is not possible. It is something the developer should
>   not care about. **For the time being, this means that interactions such
>   as drag and drop are harder to implement**, but this is intended and we
>   are working on an elegant solution for these use-cases.

**Although:** When **not** using `GenericSync`, you can use the `DOM draggable` events with a Famo.us `Surface` as you stated in the comments and link to the John Traver solution.

**But:** This solution will not work on mobile touch devices using `Famo.us` at the time of this answer. Getting this to work with `touch` may prove to be more difficult as stated in the pitfalls. Let's hope this gets solved in versions following 0.3.5 or in `MixedMode (WebGL and DOM)`

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
  var Draggable = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

  var transTransform = new TransitionableTransform();
  transTransform.set(Transform.translate(100, 0, 0));

  var captureSurface = new Surface({
    content: 'Drag to Here',
    size: [300, 300],
    properties: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      lineHeight: '300px',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.4)',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    attributes: {
      dropzone: 'copy file:image/png file:image/gif file:image/jpeg'
    }
  });
  captureSurface.on('dragenter', function(evt) {
    console.log('dragenter', evt);
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  captureSurface.on('dragleave', function(evt) {
    console.log('dragleave', evt);
    captureSurface.setProperties({
      border: 'none'
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  captureSurface.on('dragover', function(evt) {
    console.log('dragover', evt);
    captureSurface.setProperties({
      border: '4px dashed black'
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  captureSurface.on('drop', function(evt) {
    console.log('drop', evt);

    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    captureSurface.setProperties({
      border: '4px solid red'
    });

    files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
  });
  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
    align: [0.5, 0.5]
  })).add(captureSurface);

  var surface = new Surface({
    content: 'DOM Draggable',
    size: [300, 100],
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)',
      cursor: 'move'
    },
    attributes: {
      draggable: 'true'
    }
  });
  surface.on('drag', function(evt) {
    console.log('surface drag', evt)
  });
  var imageSurface = new ImageSurface({
    content: 'http://i.imgur.com/NGOwZeT.png',
    size: [100, 100],
    properties: {
      cursor: 'copy'
    },
    attributes: {
      draggable: 'true'
    }
  });
  imageSurface.on('drag', function(evt) {
    console.log('imageSurface drag', evt)
  });
  imageSurface.on('dragend', function(evt) {
    console.log('imageSurface dragend', evt)
  });

  var dragSurface = new Surface({
    content: 'Drag Me',
    size: [100, 100],
    properties: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
      cursor: 'move'
    },
    attributes: {
      draggable: 'true'
    }
  });
  dragSurface.on('dragstart', function(evt) {
    console.log('dragSurface dragstart', event, evt);
  });
  dragSurface.on('drag', function(evt) {
    console.log('dragSurface dragstart', event, evt);
  });

  var modifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0, 0],
    align: [0, 0],
    transform: transTransform
  });
  var imageModifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0, 0.5],
    align: [0, 0.5]
  });

  var draggable = new Draggable();

  draggable.subscribe(dragSurface);

  mainContext.add(modifier).add(surface);
  mainContext.add(imageModifier).add(imageSurface);
  mainContext.add(draggable).add(dragSurface);

  draggable.on('update', function(e) {
    console.log('draggable update', e, event);

    var pos = e.position;
    surface.setContent('Draggable Position is ' + pos);
    transTransform.set(Transform.translate(pos[0] + 100, pos[1], 0));
  });

  draggable.on('end', function(e) {
    var pos = e.position;
    surface.setContent('Draggable End Position is ' + pos);
    transTransform.set(Transform.translate(pos[0] + 100, pos[1], 0));
  });

  //draggable.deactivate();

});
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```