# How to return dragged fa-surface back to its origin using famo/angular?

Tags: angularjs, famo.us, famous-angular

Im using fa-draggable directive which works:

```
<fa-modifier fa-size="[90, 90]">
             <fa-draggable fa-pipe-from="item.handler"
                           fa-options="draggableOptions"
                           fa-pipe-to="item.handler">
                           <fa-surface fa-background-color="'#268bd2'"
                                       fa-pipe-to="item.handler">
                                        A
                           </fa-surface>
             </fa-draggable>
</fa-modifier>
```

And inside my controller I set:

```
$scope.draggableOptions = {
        xRange: [-4, 4],
        yRange: [-4, 4]
    };
$scope.item.handler = new EventHandler();
$scope.item.handler.on('end', function (e) {
                //return somehow to default position
            });
```

How can I assure that after drag event is done, the draggable surface is returned to default position?

I found this question [Drag a Famous surface and have it transition back to origin on mouseup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129805/drag-a-famous-surface-and-have-it-transition-back-to-origin-on-mouseup)
but I dont know how can I use "setPosition" function in my case?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129805/drag-a-famous-surface-and-have-it-transition-back-to-origin-on-mouseup)? Besides the mouse-up, it seems to be exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setPosition

```
$famous.find('fa-draggable')[0].modifier.setPosition([4,4])
```

Demo Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwLFXsjoxHyXqPpUgxJh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Last time I have used Famous/Angular, I had a similar problem and end up not using the draggable surface.
If you have a look to [the documentation](https://famo.us/integrations/angular/docs/unstable/api/directive/faDraggable/index.html), is not really useful.
BTW you could try this:

```
<fa-modifier fa-size="[90, 90]" fa-translate="item.position.get()">
             <fa-draggable fa-pipe-from="item.handler"
                           fa-options="draggableOptions"
                           fa-pipe-to="item.handler">
                           <fa-surface fa-background-color="'#268bd2'"
                                       fa-pipe-to="item.handler">
                                        A
                           </fa-surface>
             </fa-draggable>
</fa-modifier>
```

and in your controller

```
var _initialState = [0, 0, 0]; //This should be your initial state

$scope.item.position = new Transitionable(_initialState); // This define item.position as a Transitionable object
$scope.item.handler.on('end', function (e) {
   $scope.item.position.set(_initialState);
});
```

I never tried this and I have no time to do it now, but I hope the suggestion can help you.

**UPDATE**

Here is [an example](https://github.com/thomasstreet/famous-angular-examples/blob/master/app/views/draggable.html) of a view using the draggable directive.
It looks it's doing something similar to what I proposed.